# Trouble setting bool value of destination view controller in segue

Tags: ios, objective-c

As I segue from `SearchViewController` to `MatchCenterViewController`, I want to set the bool value of `_didAddNewItem` in `MatchCenterViewController` to `YES`. I'm attempting to accomplish this like so:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"ShowMatchCenterSegue"]) {
        MatchCenterViewController *controller = (MatchCenterViewController *) segue.destinationViewController;
        _didAddNewItem = YES;

        NSLog(@"we're about to set controller values before segueing to MC");
        // Send over the matching item criteria
        controller.itemPriority = self.itemPriority;

        if (_didAddNewItem == YES) {
           NSLog(@"Did add new item is YES");
        }
        [self.tabBarController setSelectedIndex:1];
    }
}
```

The destination view controller is tab 1, so I want to set the bool before it switches to that tab. It is logging out "Did add new item is YES", which tells me that the value of the bool is indeed `YES` just before segueing.

However, upon switching to the destination, when the `viewDidAppear` of the destination controller runs, it logs out "don't refresh".

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
   if (_didAddNewItem == YES) {
        NSLog(@"well then lets refresh the MC");
   }
   else if (_didAddNewItem == NO) {
        NSLog(@"dont refresh");
   }
}
```

I set the bool property in the headers of both originating and destination VC like so:

```
@property (assign) BOOL didAddNewItem;
```

Very confused as to what I'm missing here.

Answer (score 1):

You are confusing access to a property with access to the automatically synthesised iVar.

When you say

```
@property BOOL something;
```

and don't use an `@synthesize` statement the compiler will automatically create an iVar  `BOOL _something` to store the property.  You can then access this property using `self.something` or `_something`.  You should get into the habit of always using `self.something` (or `object.something` in the case of another object reference) except in initialiser methods.

In your code you are setting the local iVar _didAddNewItem when what you want is to set the property on the destination controller -

```
 controller.didAddNewItem = YES;
```